# How to play audio file in html webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio, xhtml

Here is my code:

```
<embed src="upload/audiofile/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>"  height="12px" width="150px" controller="true" autoplay="false" autostart="false" />
```

I was used this code for audio file play in webpage, But its not working in some browsers and other systems i need exact format for playing audio file in webpage to support all browsers with same view.

Comment: According to W3Schools, **"The <embed> tag is supported in all major browsers."** What browser are you trying?

Comment: i tried in Firefox its working fine but in chrome its not working its showing some different type player image @Adam Zapp and i also tried in another system it showing empty space

Comment: Here is the solution http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Comment: Well... Each browser has its on built-in audio & video player.. if you want to show **one type** of player you should find a SWF player, you can't control the player type in browser

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

audio {
width: 300px;
height: 30px;
}

**HTML**

```
<audio controls="controls">
     <source src="resources/demo-audio.ogg">
     <source src="resources/audio.mp3"> 
</audio>
```

`<audio>` is a html5 tag. 
Chrome supports most mp3 file extensions.
Firefox supports `*.ogg` by default.

Comment: Dude check this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp   firefox supports all except mp3(partial)

Comment: Firefox uses **QuickTime player** to play mp3 files!

Comment: yes exactly i m using Quick time player its working fine, but another system IE its not working @Adam Zapp

Comment: I recommend you to use your own player, like [jPlayer: Audio demo](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/)

Answer (score 0):

to autoplay you can use this in html:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="/sounds/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you still might not get the intended behavior:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes